# ListView does not render all items until interacted with

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a very strange problem while using my ListView.

Only a part of my adapter items are renderd in the listview on screen but when I interact with the listview (ie tries to scroll it) all items are renderd properly.

This fenonemon only occurs if i have less items than the screen can show. Take a look at these screenshots below.

**Before interaction:**
[image]

**After interaction:**
[image]

Source code of activity where adding items:

```
String[] jRests = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.j_restaurants);
        String[] lRests = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.l_restaurants);

        items = new ArrayList<Object>();
        items.add(getString(R.string.campus_j));
        for(String item : jRests){
            String[] val = item.split(",,,");
            items.add(new FoodSectionListItem(new Restaurant(val[0], val[1], val[2], "")));
        }   
        items.add(getString(R.string.campus_l));
        for(String item : lRests){
            String[] val = item.split(",,,");
            items.add(new FoodSectionListItem(new Restaurant(val[0], val[1], val[2], "")));
        }   

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        adapter = new BaseSectionAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_fragment_header);
        if(!isTabletView()){
            adapter.setSelectedItem(-1);
        }
        adapter.setItems(items);
```

Code of adapter:

```
public class BaseSectionAdapter extends AmazingAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int selectedItem = 0;
    private List<Object> items;
    private List<SectionItem> sections = new ArrayList<SectionItem>(10);
    private List<Class> itemTypes = new ArrayList<Class>();
    private List<Integer> sectionPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private int listHeaderLayoutId;
    private View headerView;

    public static interface ISectionListItem {
        public void setProps(View convertView, int position, int selectedItem);
        public View getLayout(LayoutInflater inflater);
    }

    private class SectionItem implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8930010937740160935L;
        String text;
        int position;

        public SectionItem(String text, int position) {
            this.text = text;
            this.position = position;
        }
    }

    public BaseSectionAdapter(Context context, int listHeaderLayoutId) {
        this.listHeaderLayoutId = listHeaderLayoutId;
        init(context);
    }

    public BaseSectionAdapter(Context context, int listHeaderLayoutId, List<Object> listItems) {
        this.listHeaderLayoutId = listHeaderLayoutId;
        init(context);
        initListItems(listItems);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
        selectedItem = position;
    }

//  public List<ListItem> getItems() {
//      return items;
//  }

    private void initListItems(List<Object> itemList) {
        int curSection = -1;
        //int curPosition = 0;
        //curSection = 0;

        this.items = itemList;
        itemTypes.clear();
        sections.clear();
        sectionPositions.clear();



        int listSize = itemList.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
            Object currentItem = items.get(i);
            if(currentItem instanceof String){
                sections.add(new SectionItem((String) currentItem,i));
                curSection++;
            }
            if(!itemTypes.contains(currentItem.getClass())){
                itemTypes.add(currentItem.getClass());
            }


            sectionPositions.add(curSection);
        }

        Log.d("test", "No of items = "+items.size());
        Log.d("test", "No of itemtypes = "+itemTypes.size());
        Log.d("test", "View type count = "+getViewTypeCount());
    }

    public void setItems(List<Object> itemList) {
        initListItems(itemList);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return items==null?0:items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount(){
        return (itemTypes.size() == 0)?1:itemTypes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        return itemTypes.indexOf(items.get(position).getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position){
        return !(items.get(position) instanceof String || items.get(position) instanceof EmptySectionListItem);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNextPageRequested(int page) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void bindSectionHeader(View view, int position,
            boolean displaySectionHeader) {
//      TextView lSectionTitle = (TextView) view
//              .findViewById(R.id.txt_list_header);
//      if (displaySectionHeader) {
//          lSectionTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//          lSectionTitle
//                  .setText(getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);
//      } else {
//          lSectionTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//      }
    }

    @Override
    public View getAmazingView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Object curItemObject = items.get(position);
        boolean isHeader = (curItemObject instanceof String);

        if(convertView == null){
            if(isHeader && headerView != null){
                convertView = headerView;
            }else if(isHeader){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(listHeaderLayoutId, null);
                headerView = convertView;
            }else{
                convertView = ((ISectionListItem) curItemObject).getLayout(inflater);
            }
        }   
        if(isHeader){
            TextView header = ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_header));
            header.setText((String)curItemObject);
        }else{
            ((ISectionListItem)curItemObject).setProps(convertView, position, selectedItem);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePinnedHeader(View header, int position, int alpha) {

        TextView textView = ((TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.txt_list_header));
        textView.setText(getSections()[getSectionForPosition(position)]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        if(section >= sections.size()){
            return 0;
        }

        return sections.get(section).position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return sectionPositions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSections() {
        String[] res = new String[sections.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            res[i] = sections.get(i).text;

        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Code of layout:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            FrameLayout listLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams listParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            listParams.weight = 1;
            listLayout.setId(LIST_FRAGMENT_VIEW_ID);

            FrameLayout detailLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams detailParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            detailParams.weight = 2;
            detailLayout.setId(DETAIL_FRAGMENT_VIEW_ID);

            layout.addView(listLayout, listParams);
            layout.addView(detailLayout, detailParams);

            if(savedInstanceState == null){

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            ft.add(listLayout.getId(), (Fragment) listFragment, TWO_PANEL_LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG);
            ft.add(detailLayout.getId(), detailFragment);
            ft.commit();

            }
            setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: can you add some code of adapter..?

Comment: add the source code where you are adding items to your backing data source of your listview, and creatting the adapter

Comment: show your ListView's layout source too. :)

Comment: added all the stuff you asked for, altough, the structure is pretty complex :)

Comment: can you share what changes u made. i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!!!

Problem was with the adapter trying to reuse the same section item. Not good!!!

Changed it to inflate the section item each time we hit a section!

Comment: can you please help me, i have the same problem , can you explain how your resolved it? i have to click on the screen to load listview

Comment: a proper answer should elaborate how to solve the problem, not just hint it. especially if you answer your own question...

Answer (score 6):

try calling notifyDataSetChanged() in runOnUIThread() method like I have shown below and it will work like a charm. :)

```
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Apparently not the solution for the original question, but this solved the same problem for me. Calling notifyDataSetChanged() from another thread isn't reliable.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what causes the problem, but if you don't find a logical solution to it you could try something like this:

- trigger an `onTouchEvent()` programmatically whenever you launch the `ListView`.
- scroll down and back up programmatically as soon as the ListView is launched.

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Add ListView widget to layout.xml and add content of list to that. Do not use FrameLayout as it probably is the cause of the problem. It is updating content after touch so the Layout it is on is no implementing the correct onCreate() setup as the ListView widget has.

Comment: what do you mean it is not implementing the correct onCreate?

Im creating the layout programatically, which i then add my fragments to. Tried changing the two FrameLayout to LinearLayout, made no difference :/

Comment: @Richard Where are you adding a ListView? According to your code you are not implementing a ListView.

Comment: `ft.add(listLayout.getId(), (Fragment) listFragment, TWO_PANEL_LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG);`

im adding a listfragment

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the method notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter after adding new items? This causes the listview to refresh its view when the underlying dataset is changed.

If it still doesn't work, try notifyDataSetInvalidated() that causes the listview to redraw completely.

Comment: Tried this one. Has no effect. Beginning to think the listfragment might be the issue here.

Im adding